# Changing artist name on itunes without changing to unknown album

Tags: itunes

I like to keep my itunes neat and organised, so naturally I like to keep the correct artist name for each song. Unfortunately, I have a problem. This only happens with one song, it's in a compilation so the artist originally listed on the song was 'various artists', and while I have no such issue with any of the other songs, when I change the artist name on this particular track, the song is suddenly listed as 'unknown album' and the only way to change it back is to change the artist back to various. All of the songs in the album share the same album artist so I don't know why this would happen, particularly with this one song. I cant find anything about this issue anywhere so it would be great if someone could help.

Comment: Can you post a link to a screenshot of song’s Get Info information?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the ID3 tags?

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install mutagen
mid3v2 --delete-all song.mp3
```